# Unable to use Aspect around over a method

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

This is in a Spring project where I have Aspect setup in a different module on which other modules are dependent. I am using custom annotations. It works fine on some methods but not on others. Could I get advice on what the problem is?

This Aspect class is coming from a module and other modules are dependent on this.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class VirtualizeJsonAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(virtualizeJson)")
    public Object virtualizeJsonAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, VirtualizeJson virtualizeJson) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Class returnType = signature.getReturnType();
    // ....... This is working fine
}
```

The following 3 classes are in the same module, if relevant.

It works here when I try to use Aspect:

Path for reference -> com/domain/abc/service/helper/DataHelper.java

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:something.properties")
public class DataHelper {

    @VirtualizeJson(serviceNm = "ABC", virtualizedDataPath = "/url/some.json")
    public SomeResponse getOffers(SomeRequest someRequest){

        HttpEntity httpRequestEntity = createRequestEntity(request);

        ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> httpResponseEntity;
        SomeResponse someResponse = null;
        // ......... Aspect works here. I do not get in here. Instead I land in the Aspect class as expected
    }
}
```

Config file
Path for reference -> com/domain/abc/service/config/AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {{"com.domain.virtualize"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
    // some bean setups not relevant to Aspect
}
```

It is not working here when I try to use the Aspect:

Path for reference -> com/domain/abc/service/rules/CheckSomething.java

```
@Component
public class CheckSomething extends SomeRule {

    @VirtualizeJson(serviceNm = "ABC", virtualizedDataPath = "/url/some.json")
    public SomeResponse checkOffers(String someNumber){

        int a = 1;
        return null;
        // I land inside this method which is incorrect. I shouldh have landed at the Aspect class instead 
    }
}
```

Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface VirtualizeJson {
    public String serviceNm();
    public String virtualizedDataPath();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you copy the package names into your code snippets instead of manually writing down the source paths? Besides, according to those paths your components seems to be in package `com.domain.abc.service` but your component scan targets `com.domain.virtualize`. So is your config wrong or did you manipulate the file paths in the wrong way for reference here? Either way it is inconsistent and does not make much sense.

Comment: Hello, anyone there? If you ask a question and someone tries to help you with hints and follow-up questions, maybe some feedback would be helpful.